# Personalize an Email Campaign message

Tags: exm, personalization

I am working on the personalization of the Email Campaign OOTB of Sitecore 9 Update 1. What I need to do is to be able to send a content to specific segments of recipients/contacts.

What I did:

1. Created Two Contact lists
2. Added both to the "Include List" in the Email Campaign
3. Personalized a rendering.

[image]

[image]

I did it to the other Contact List I created. But when i checked the Emails, both received the same content. Why?

Comment: Which version of EXM is this? Did you enable the personalization checkbox c.f. https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/creating_and_editing_messages/sending_messages/send_an_email_campaign?

Comment: This is operating in EXM Sitecore 9.0.1 and yes, the checkbox for personalization was enabled prior sending.

Comment: See Pete's answer. You need the cumulative hotfix for 9.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if the version of Sitecore/EXM were listed in the question, as this could be a result of many different issues. However, based on the information provided, I am led to believe that the user is operating on Sitecore 9.0.1 EXM.  If this is the case, there is a known issue with personalization.

Referencing the [Cumulative hotfix for EXM 9.0 Update-1](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/467253) from Sitecore, this hotfix includes a number of fixes for issues found in 9.0.1 EXM. Of these issues, is the Analytics Personalization, which wasn't being applied to the message body. In short, the personalization you are attempting to use requires the use of the Analytics Tracker which is unavailable OOTB with Sitecore 9.0.1 EXM.

Installing this hotfix (or upgrading to Sitecore 9.0.2) fixes this issue.  Other issues fixed listed in this hotfix include:

> - Segmented Lists are not considered as a contact data source during the dispatch process.
> - Attachments cannot be removed from a message.
> - The Click Email Link goal usage can lead to an exception in log files.
> - The number of Sent metrics in the message statistics is wrong.
> - Message statistics are not updated properly because of caching.
> - Analytics personalization may not be applied to the message body.
> - NullReferenceException may be thrown if Email facet is empty.
> - Dispatch may be paused if used lists contain PII sensitive data.